# get info by tag name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a way to capture all the text fields of unknown quantity and save them as a JSON: I'm pretty comfortable coding but new to web. Is this even the way to do it? thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myP">
        field
        <br />
    </div>
    <button onclick="addField()">add field</button>
    <button onclick="captureAllInfo()">Capture</button>
    <script>
        var whichdiv = 0;
      
        function addField() {
          whichdiv = whichdiv + 1;
          parentDocument = document.getElementById("myP");
      
          var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
          mydiv.id = whichdiv;
      
          var input1 = document.createElement("input");
          var label1 = document.createElement("label");
          label1.innerHTML = "input label 1 ";
          input1.id = "Info1";
      
          var input2 = document.createElement("input");
          var label2 = document.createElement("label");
          label2.innerHTML = "imput label 2";
          input2.id = "Info2";
      
          mydiv.appendChild(label1);
          mydiv.appendChild(input1);
          mydiv.appendChild(label2);
          mydiv.appendChild(input2);
      
          parentDocument.appendChild(mydiv);
        }
      
        function captureAllInfo() {
          for (var i = 0; i < whichdiv; i++) {
            console.log("loopin");
            var thisDiv = document.getElementById(i);
            console.log(thisDiv.getElementById("Info1").value);
          }
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Really what I would like to do is get those two inputs and then add them to a JSON object like 
JSON STRUCTURE as below:

```
{
  "1": 
      {input1 : "string",
       input2: "String"},
    "2": 
      {input1 : "string", 
       input2: "String"}
     "3"..., 
     "4"...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a function like this `document.querySelectorAll('input')`.

This will fetch all the input elements that exist in your DOM. And then you can modify them as per your requirement.

Comment: check the spell `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @prasanth thanks for correction `q` key seems buggy on my keyboard.

Comment: But once I have it, how do I identify which 'input' is which?

Comment: @RyanB.  we can iterate over the array we get from this function and check their id's....

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive the bad formatting of my function. I wrote this on my fairphone2. The idea is that I used `className` for the repeated identifiers. Please also note that purely numeric `id` tags should be avoided.

```html
<html>
<div id="myP">
  field
  <br />
</div>
<button onclick="addField()">add field</button>
<button onclick="captureAllInfo()">Capture</button>
<script>
  var whichdiv = 0;

  function addField() {
    whichdiv = whichdiv + 1;
    parentDocument = document.getElementById("myP");

    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    mydiv.id = 'd'+whichdiv;
    mydiv.className='idiv';

    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var label1 = document.createElement("label");
    label1.innerHTML = "input label 1 ";
    input1.className = "Info1";

    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    var label2 = document.createElement("label");
    label2.innerHTML = "input label 2";
    input2.className = "Info2";

    mydiv.appendChild(label1);
    mydiv.appendChild(input1);
    mydiv.appendChild(label2);
    mydiv.appendChild(input2);

    parentDocument.appendChild(mydiv);
  }
function qsa(s,o){return [...(o||document).querySelectorAll(s)]}
function captureAllInfo() {var o={};
  qsa('.idiv').forEach(d=>{
   var c=o[d.id.substr(1)]={};  
   qsa('input',d).forEach(t=>c[t.className]=t.value);
  });
 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  }
</script>

</html>
```

**Edit**:. 
I added the shortcut function `qsa()` for the various "QuerySelectorAll" methods to make everything a bit more readable. `qsa()` returns an Array instead of a simple nodelist. The second argument in `qsa()` is optional. If given it will be the element for which the `.querySelectorAll()` method will be called. It defaults to `document`.